# How to access one App's Database to another Application using Sqlite?

Tags: android, database, android-sqlite, sqliteopenhelper, sqlite

I have two applications which resulting to use database.

Application A which creates database name DB1. This database I wanted to access in 
application B. The applications are in different packages.

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 2):

Application are not allowed to read private data of another application (you can do this only on rooted devices). The easiest way is to store database in some public location, but that is **not recommend** because any app on device will have access to database file...

Here is what you can do. You can create `BroadcastReceiver`-s from both sides and implement your communication protocol using message passing. Application B will broadcast requests, application A will handle that request and send result back to the application B. The only problem is that application A code must be updated to. For more info on how to use message passing, check [this article](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html)

Comment: thanks...Can we do this using Content Provoider??  and how ??

Comment: I think [this](http://www.grokkingandroid.com/android-tutorial-writing-your-own-content-provider/) can help you...

Comment: Thanks XeNoN.. yes Definitely this tutorial helps me.

Answer (score 1):

you need to have both applications installed using same user id. Add this to both manifests:

```
android:sharedUserId="com.abc.xyz"
```